# Problem with commiting a mutator to vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a little problem, I'm posting an HTTP request, then updating the vuex store, then trying to clear all the form fields and the instance variables of the component(using the reset values function), somehow my app is clearing the fields before updating the store, and then it updates the store with empty values, any ideas what is the problem?
this is the code:

```js
axios({
    url: "/boards",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    data: formData
}).then(() => {
    this.$store.commit("addBoard", this.boardDetails)
    this.resetValues() //clearing the values
});
```

this is the mutation in store:

```js
addBoard: (state, payload) => state.boards.push(payload)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `boardDetails` is an object, which are passed by reference in JS, so the object that gets added to the `boards` array in the store is the same one that's holding the form state in your component.

When you call `resetValues()`, you're probably setting the `boardDetails` object's properties back to their defaults, which is also reflected in the store (as it's the same object in both).

You could fix this by creating a new payload object with the form values:

```
this.$store.commit("addBoard", { ...this.boardDetails })
```